# python: subprocess.Popen, openvpn command not found

Tags: python, path, subprocess, jupyter

`OS X 10.13.6` `Python 3.6`

I am trying to run the following command from a jupyter notebook:

```
vpn_cmd = '''
sudo openvpn 
--config ~/Downloads/configs/ipvanish-US-Chicago-chi-a49.ovpn 
--ca ~/Downloads/configs/ca.ipvanish.com.crt'''

proc = Popen(vpn_cmd.split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
print(stdout.decode())
```

But get the error:

> sudo: openvpn: command not found

What I've tried:

- added `export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"` to my ~/.bash_profile and can run the the `sudo openvpn` command from my terminal
- edited my sudoers file so `sudo` no longer prompts for a password
- called `sudo which openvpn` and tried adding `/usr/local/sbin/openvpn` to my sys.path within python
- not splitting `vpn_cmd` and setting `shell=True`
- tried packaging it in a test.py script and executing from the terminal, but it just hangs at the `proc.communicate()` line
- specified the full path for the `--config` and `--ca` flags

So far, nothing has fixed this. I can run `openvpn` from my terminal just fine. It seems like a simple path issue but I can't figure out what I need to add to my python path. Is there something particular with the jupyter notebook kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jupyter probably isn't picking up your personal `.bashrc` settings, depending also on how you are running it. Just hardcode the path or augment the `PATH` in your Python script instead.

With `shell=False` you don't get the tildes expanded; so you should change those to `os.environ["HOME"]`, or make sure you know in which directory you run this, and use relative paths.

You should not be using `Popen()` if `run` can do what you require.

```
home = os.environ["HOME"]
r = subprocess.run(
    ['sudo', '/usr/local/sbin/openvpn', 
     '--config',  home + '/Downloads/configs/ipvanish-US-Chicago-chi-a49.ovpn', 
     '--ca', home + '/Downloads/configs/ca.ipvanish.com.crt'],
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
print(r.stdout)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that did it. Good to know about run vs Popen, I will read up on that.

Comment: Sorry, I did try upvoting but it said my reputation is too low. I was able to accept it though